# PrintStream Println behaves differently on diff machines?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple server and client software. The server running on mac and have my custom code written in C to emulate a readline from socket.

Client written in java for android and windows machine. I am observing strange behaviour from Println call. the code looks like this

```
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());   
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseMap);
    String buffer = json.toString();
    ps.println(buffer);
    ps.flush();
```

The println when run on windows, sends /r/n after the buffer string.
The println when run on android, sends /n after the buffer string.

Should the behaviour of println not be consistent accross diff OS/machines ?

Comment: No, it should not. Line endings are platform-specific.

Comment: @GregS so is it OS specific or hardware specific ?

Comment: It's really java installation specific, but in practice that means OS specific, not hardware specific. The whole notion of a "line" tends to be OS-specific.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. I think I need to change my c code to be able to entertain all diff types of line endings without doing an early read and making sure it does not read partial readlines.. :/

Answer (score 0):

> Should the behaviour of println not be consistent accross diff OS/machines ?

The `PrintStream` retrieves the platform's line separator and sends that to the underlying stream.

Windows and Android have different line separators.

Answer (score 0):

> Should the behaviour of println not be consistent accross diff OS/machines ?

No. I don't know where you got that idea. The behaviour you describe is [***as documented***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()):

> The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').